# php form not sending date through to database SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms, submission

I have setup a form using HTML & PHP. I am sending all of my information submitted from the form to an SQL database. When I submit the form I get the error code below:

```
ERROR: Could not execute INSERT INTO `timesheets` (`Name`, `weekending`, `monin`, `monout`, `tuein`, `tueout`, `wedin`, `wedout`, `thursin`, `thursout`, `friin`, `friout`, `satin`, `satout`, `sunin`, `sunout`) VALUES ('Nathan Langer','07:30','16:00','18:00','19:00','06:30','15:00','03:00','16:00','05:00','16:00','00:00','00:00','00:00','00:00'). Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

As you can see the date does not get pushed through ( should be in between Nathan Langer & 07:30.

My submission code is below:

```
<?php
/* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "pass", "dbname");

// Check connection
if($link === false){
die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Escape user inputs for security
$Name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['Name']);
$insertdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['weekending']));
$monin = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['monin']);
$monout = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['monout']);
$tuein = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['tuein']);
$tueout = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['tueout']);
$wedin = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['wedin']);
$wedout = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['wedout']);
$thursin = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['thursin']);
$thursout = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['thursout']);
$friin = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['friin']);
$friout = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['friout']);
$satin = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['satin']);
$satout = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['satout']);
$sunin = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['sunin']); 
$sunout = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['sunout']);


// attempt insert query execution
$sql = "INSERT INTO `timesheets` (`Name`, `weekending`, `monin`, `monout`,      `tuein`, `tueout`, `wedin`, `wedout`, `thursin`, `thursout`, `friin`, `friout`, `satin`, `satout`, `sunin`, `sunout`) VALUES ('$Name','$monin','$monout','$tuein','$tueout','$wedin','$wedout','$thursin','$thursout','$friin','$friout','$satin','$satout','$sunin','$sunout')";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
header('location:timesheets.php');
} else{
echo "ERROR: Could not execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

// close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Is this because I am doing something wrong with the date in the submission form? the date field in the form is below:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6" >
<div class="input-group">
<span class="input-group-addon">
<i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
</span>
<input type="date" id="weekending" class="form-control " name="weekending" placeholder="Week Ending">
</div>                                              
</div>
```

Please can someone help me find where the issue is and why it won't post through to the database?

Comment: Value in query and value in database table is not match...you are missing any value in query

Comment: @V5Nathan you missed value `$insertdate` in insert value thats why date is not inserting....check and verify again your query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change from

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `timesheets` (`Name`, `weekending`, `monin`, `monout`,`tuein`, `tueout`, `wedin`, `wedout`, `thursin`, `thursout`, `friin`, `friout`, `satin`, `satout`, `sunin`, `sunout`) VALUES ('$Name','$monin','$monout','$tuein','$tueout','$wedin','$wedout','$thursin','$thursout','$friin','$friout','$satin','$satout','$sunin','$sunout')";
```

to

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `timesheets` (`Name`, `weekending`, `monin`, `monout`,`tuein`, `tueout`, `wedin`, `wedout`, `thursin`, `thursout`, `friin`, `friout`, `satin`, `satout`, `sunin`, `sunout`) VALUES ('$Name','$insertdate','$monin','$monout','$tuein','$tueout','$wedin','$wedout','$thursin','$thursout','$friin','$friout','$satin','$satout','$sunin','$sunout')";
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing more columns than no. of values,

So you need to correct query by adding one more column name or remove one value.

```
INSERT INTO `timesheets` (`Name`, `weekending`, `monin`, `monout`, `tuein`, 
`tueout`, `wedin`, `wedout`, `thursin`, `thursout`, `friin`, `friout`, 
`satin`, `satout`, `sunin`, `sunout`) VALUES ('Nathan 
Langer','07:30','16:00','18:00','19:00','06:30','15:00','03:00','16:00','05:00',
'16:00','00:00','00:00','00:00','00:00', '00:00')
```

Above code will work as i added one more value in it.